# Ubuntu Phone sleep command

Tags: ubuntu-touch, suspend, upstart

I want to use a small script initiated by upstart to periodically synchronise calendar and contacts.

The script works and it is started by upstart.

Since it is in an endless loop until stopped I use the sleep command in order to make it wait for the next cycle. However I found out that the sleep command does not behave in the same way it does on other Linux and Unix systems. Basically the time it waits is significantly longer than indicated (i. e.  a wait for 60s takes about 3 mins).

I assume this has something to do with the battery saving options and sleep modes of the phone as such.

Is there a way for this kind of device to have a sleep which times correctly?